# Where javascript variables are stored

Tags: javascript, variables

I know it is stupid, but I cannot figure out where javascript variables are stored: on a hard drive or in RAM? Is there a way to force store to a specific place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript variables are stored in the memory of the browser process.

There are several kinds of 'variables' you might want to think about:

1. Variables in JavaScript code, which are saved in the memory of the browser process.
2. Cookies can also store variables; they are often saved on your hard disk;

Answer (score 3):

The language itself doesn't specify where or how anything is stored, though most will be stored in RAM.

Some integers may get stored in registers -- but not all processors even have registers.

But in short, no, you can't take direct control of any of that.  In fact, the language is designed to remove you from any of the low-level details.

To access direct memory, you need to use a language like `C` or `assembly` -- and even then it can be quite tricky as the memory manager may give you a block of memory and say 'that's it -- that's all that is available' and isolated you from everything else.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in RAM.

Since its an Implementation-Specific thing, you cannot control it.